# Xcode 8 crashes on storyboard view and displays only blue outlines around views

Tags: crash, autolayout, storyboard, xcode8

[image]

I have Updated Xcode yesterday from version 7 to version 8.1 overnight and deleted the xcode 8.0 beta that i had!

Today I tried to Open all my projects, and when I go to the storyboard, I get the following Error..

An internal Error Occured. Editing Functionality may be limited. Report a Bug (which I did).

The project that I opened, does not use size classes or autolayout.

I have searched many questions on the net, which pointed that the problem is caused by projects without autolayout. or suggested that i clean xcode, simulator, deleted derived data folder.. all without success..
I also tried saving the storyboard as an Xcode7x file with no success..

Finally I tried creating a new SingleView Application and added a UIButton to it.. (while using size classes, autolayout..) still the same.. so it's definitely an Xcode Bug issue.. Not an autolayout incompatibility problem.

any hints?

p.s. compiling the project will actually run great, and all ui elements will show as intended. I don't have Xcode7 installed anymore.. any suggestions?

Comment: Off-topic but maybe helpful in the future: Whenever I update Xcode, I first copy `/Applications/Xcode.app` to `/Applications/Xcode_v_X_x_x.app` (v_7_2_1 for example).

Comment: I used to do that as well.. however, as i had xcode beta in parallel and it didn't have any issues.. I didn't bother this time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed when i updated xcode!

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the crashe, but I could fix messed up UI by setting up the following under `Editor` menu -> `Canvas`:

[image]

Comment: No further idea, sorry. Good luck!